# Reset to default language in Outlook 2010 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010

In Outlook 2010, if I accidently, hit left Ctrl-Shift, my language changes. I keep hitting it and get a new language, but I can't get back to English.

How do I reset back to my default language? Going to *Control Panel* -> *Language and Region* and hitting default there does not work.

Also, how do I configure my Outlook 2010 and all MS Office products to NEVER change the language? I only want to use English.

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to make sure that your english language is the default it may not be so therefore your windows and other program maybe confused because of that.
So head back to control panel locate regional and language option click details you will see a box field that shows you the list of languages on that back if you see any other language other then english just delete it. Hit apply once it's done.
restart your computer once you're windows is back go to your office 2010 go to file look for option and locate language make sure you see the English U.S or Ca as default if not remove whatever it detects and add if you need too. This also a display option make sure that they're also english by default that hopefully that should correct this problem of yours.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about the keyboard layout, correct?

If you are only going to use English, you should delete all other Languages in your Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Keyboards and Languages -> Change Keyboard

Under General you can now remove other Keyboards.